# Run main method from GUI button in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I have a Main class file that runs automatically when I run the program, but I don’t want this to happen. I want the GUI to come up first and then with a click of a button, I want my process to run. Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand? Are you asking how to make a GUI? How to handle a button click? How to call your function?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the Main class and the GUI? You need to be more specific and also show some code. Also the fact that you say _"I’m new to java and NetBeans"_ Tells me that you're trying to learn GUI programming with the GUI Builder design tool. You will constantly run into problems if you don't first understand how to hand code. Take a look at [Creating GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and try and go through some tutorials.

Comment: I have a GUI in design view with a label, and two buttons.  i have named this GUI.java and it is a jPanel form. then i have all my other classes (main.java etc), but these run automatically before my GUI does anything.

Comment: In short: No. In long: The code in your main method always runs when you press play. What you want is Joel's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You need a main method in order to start up your GUI. However, if add an `ActionListener` to your `JButton`, you can set code to be run when the button is clicked. Therefore, you can move the code that currently runs in your main method to the `actionPerformed()` method of the `ActionListener` to achieve the effect you're looking for.

**Example**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me.");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("This is the code that runs when you press the button.");
            }

        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button click tester");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, is there anyway to use the design view to add elements such as labels to my gui this way or do i need to write the commands in like you have above?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with NetBean's GUI builder, but it's probably possible. With that said, though, you *really* should learn to code by hand as *peeskillet* already said.